# Remove the words that describe the post on Tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I would like to get rid of the underlined "photo" next to posted pictures and the "text" above the posted text.

Template section for text posts

```
{block:Text}
<div class="post text">
    <span class="icon"><a href="{Permalink}">{lang:Text}</a></span>
    <span class="meta">
        <a href="/day/{Year}/{MonthNumberWithZero}/{DayOfMonthWithZero}/" class="timestamp"><b>{DayOfMonth}</b>&nbsp;{ShortMonth}</a>                {block:IfDisqusShortname}<a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread" class="count"></a>{block:IfDisqusShortname}
        {block:IfShowNotes}{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}" class="count note">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{block:NoteCount}{block:IfShowNotes}
    </span>
    {block:Title}<span class="ttl"><a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a></span>{/block:Title}
    <div class="body">
    {Body}
    </div>
    {block:RebloggedFrom} 
    <div class="source">
    via <a href="{ReblogParentURL}">{ReblogParentTitle}</a>.
    </div>
    {/block:RebloggedFrom}
</div>
{/block:Text}
```

Template section for photo posts

```
{block:Photo}
<div class="post photo">
    <span class="icon"><a href="{Permalink}">{lang:Photo}</a></span>
    <span class="meta">
        <a href="/day/{Year}/{MonthNumberWithZero}/{DayOfMonthWithZero}/" class="timestamp"><b>{DayOfMonth}</b>&nbsp;{ShortMonth}</a>                {block:IfDisqusShortname}<a href="{Permalink}#disqus_thread" class="count"></a>{block:IfDisqusShortname}
        {block:IfShowNotes}{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}" class="count note">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{block:NoteCount}{block:IfShowNotes}
    </span>
    {LinkOpenTag}<img src="{PhotoURL-500}" alt="{PhotoAlt}">{LinkCloseTag}
    {block:Caption}
    <div class="body">
    {Caption}
    </div>
    {/block:Caption}
    {block:RebloggedFrom} 
    <div class="source">
    via <a href="{ReblogParentURL}">{ReblogParentTitle}</a>.
    </div>
    {/block:RebloggedFrom}
</div>
{/block:Photo}
```

How can I remove the text that labels what the post is?

Comment: We'd need to see your template

Comment: If nothing else this should give you a good laugh- I have no idea what I'm doing :).

Comment: I made changes by trial and error on a theme that was already there.  If there are any other problems I would greatly appreciate someone pointing them out.

Comment: What happens when you remove `<span class="icon"><a href="{Permalink}">{lang:Photo}</a></span>` from the template?

Comment: The underlined "photo" goes away!  Thank you so very much!

Answer (score 1):

In both sections, you'll want to remove these parts specifically from the template:

```
<span class="icon"><a href="{Permalink}">{lang:Text}</a></span>
```

The above will remove the "text" phrase from text posts. The above will remove "photo" from photo posts.

```
<span class="icon"><a href="{Permalink}">{lang:Photo}</a></span>
```

Keep in mind that these are also the permalinks to the post themselves. That means if you wanted to show just that page you may have a harder time with the photo posts than the text posts are the permalink is still in the title.

If you want to add the permalink, you need this part:

```
<a href="{Permalink}">XYZ</a>
```

and replace the XYZ with the part of the post you want to create a link from. But you can just leave it off all the same.